# UITabBarItem and selection one of the view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

It's possible select the UITabBarItem desired in a TabBarController with 4 UITabBarItem with a click on a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just set the tab bar controller's `selectedViewController` or `selectedIndex` property to the desired view controller or tab index.

Comment: I am in one of the UITabBarItem which kind of action can i write to do this? thanks